# API Magento catalogCategoryUpdate function not working after moving to SSL

Tags: soap, category-products, soap-api-v2

I was working with SOAP on Magento like

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://host/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
```

and after moving to

```
    $client = new SoapClient('https://host/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
```

the functions of categories like

```
$client->catalogCategoryMove
```

or

```
$client->catalogCategoryUpdate
```

stop working, and I'm having:

```
SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Service Unavailable
```

this is my Stack Trace

```
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://admin.c...', 'urn:Mage_Api_Mo...', 1, 0)

#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/ws/categorias_v2.php(161): SoapClient->__call('catalogCategory...', Array)

#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/ws/categorias_v2.php(161): SoapClient->catalogCategoryUpdate('e90af090b02de56...', '9', Array)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.